# Can i have a build goal that excludes from a WAR static files (.js, .css, images) and another build goal to export these static files

Tags: maven

I am trying to get Maven to exclude from a Tomcat bound WAR static files as these will be served via Apache, and yet another build goal to package these static files so that i can deploy them separately to Apache.

Answer (score 2):

Exclude resources by configuring your pom accordingly, http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html, maven-resources-plugin provides for that.

[Assemblies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html) are also an option.

As for exporting the files, I'd call it a second artifact of the same project which is not healthy as it breaks modularity, [How to Create Two JARs from One Project (…and why you shouldn't)](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic case of a multi module project.

- One module for your static files (that you can pack as a jar or as a zip)
- Second module for the rest of your code

As @patrungel suggested, don't mix them in the same module.

I hope this helps.